# Being mighty a master, being a father and fond: what "fond" is?

Tags: meaning, poetry

I'm not sure of the meaning of the last word in the last line of G.M. Hopkin's "[In the valley of the Elwy](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/In_the_Valley_of_the_Elwy)":

```
 God, lover of souls, swaying considerate scales,
 Complete thy creature dear O where it fails
 Being mighty a master, being a father and fond.
```

Is that an adjective, i.e. *fond* = affectionate?
Or is that a noun, since *father* is a noun too?
If that's a noun, what's the meaning? Foundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes here fond is adjective, i.e. liking or affection. "Being a father and 
affectionate of souls."